# AoG Report State Dashboard state changed, but state in Google home APP didn't change

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I follow the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/report-state) step by step. And now in Report State Dashboard the state of my device will change immediately when I turn on/off my device. But the state of device dose not change in Google Home APP.

[image: google home]
[image: dashboard]

as you can see in dashboard it display on:false, but in Google Home APP it still on.

Comment: @Nick Felker, please take a look

Comment: This is a known issue. You're doing the right thing. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/308#issuecomment-475363020).

Answer (score 0):

In order for device states to update correctly in Google Home App, your action needs to implement [Report State](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/report-state) and [Query](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/intents#query) Intent correctly. Currently Google Home App depends on a combination of your report state information, and your query responses.

Also note that the Report State Dashboard Tool is now deprecated, and might show false positive results! Please use the new [Home Graph Viewer](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/tools/home-graph-viewer) going forward.